# Is using Constructs as parents for resources a bad practice?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

After using `CDK` for a couple of years now, one question came to my mind lately which regards to `Logical Ids` and `Constructs` hierarchy .

As of today I always organize my construct in a parent-child hierarchy like so:

```py
class SomeStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: App, id_: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id_, **kwargs)

        buckets_construct = MyBucketsConstruct(self, 'BucketsConstruct')

class MyBucketsConstruct(Construct):
    def __init__(self, stack: Stack, id_: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(stack, id_)
        self.bucket1 = Bucket(self, 'Bucket1')
        self.bucket2 = Bucket(self, 'Bucket2')
```

In this approach the logical ids which will be created for each bucket are calculated by the concatenation of the the parent constructs logical ids + resource id +  hash, so something like: `BucketsConstructBucket1A6591A94`, `BucketsConstructBucket2A6591A94`.

And of course that means that any movement of one of the buckets outside the BucketsConstruct will translate to a change in the logical id.. which is a painful pitfall.

Over the years I took it for granted and made sure that if I move a Construct around I persist the Logical Id by using the CfnConstruct.overrideLogicalId() function.
In addition I've tried to use CDK diff to catch this scenarios in my pipeline before it occurs.

So finally I came to realisation lately that the CDK algorithms to control the logical Ids causes more issues than anything, so i've simply started putting every resource under the `Stack` construct directly, this eliminates this pitfall. It would look like:

```py
class SomeStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: App, id_: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id_, **kwargs)

        buckets = MyBucketsConstruct(self, 'BucketsConstruct')

class MyBucketsConstruct:
    def __init__(self, stack_scope: Stack) -> None:
        self.bucket1 = Bucket(stack_scope, 'Bucket1')
        self.bucket2 = Bucket(stack_scope, 'Bucket2')
```

I would like to get some opinions.
The only pro i see in using the child construct scope for the Ids might be maybe in infrastructure shared constructs, where I might want to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0):

From the CDK [Construct Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-constructs) (docs in blockquote, my comments in plain text):

> [W]hen building your application's higher-level logical units from multiple AWS resources, represent each logical unit as a Construct, not as a Stack.

In other words, constructs encapsulate related resources.

> For example, if one of your logical units is a website, the constructs that make it up (such as an Amazon S3 bucket, API Gateway, Lambda functions, or Amazon RDS tables) should be composed into a single high-level construct. Then that construct should be instantiated in one or more stacks for deployment.

The more your resources form a related "logical unit" that deploys together, the better the construct pattern will work.

> By using constructs for building and stacks for deploying, you improve reuse potential of your infrastructure and give yourself more flexibility in how it's deployed.

To address the resource access problem you mention, you could relax the encapsulation.  Take for example the S3 bucket from the above website scenario.  You could:

1. Expose the S3 bucket as a construct property to permit other constructs [interact with it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_interact).
2. Accept an arbitrary S3 bucket reference [as a prop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_config), instead of tightly-coupling it within the construct.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, doesn't really address the breaking logical id scenario I described though, I found a good post here(I'll keep using plain classes instead of Constructs): https://repost.aws/questions/QUQ4nkD8TbQqqF8JsnG8hDGA/cdk-code-refactoring-best-practices-regarding-constructs-vs-simple-classes-logical-ids-and-stateful-resources